# What does "channel" mean in the context of deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am a beginner in deep learning and while I was studying it, I came across the term "channel" several times, such as quantization channel,  input channels, and output channels. Nevertheless, I am still confused about what it meant and its difference with feature maps. Can anyone clarify this for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I have heard, It means the "third dimension" of your data. So an image is `x` pixels long, `y` pixels wide and one channel if it is a black-white image, or three channels if it is a RGB image (one channel for each colour). I this case your tensor will be of size `x * y * number of channels`. I guess the term channel  can be used in other areas than images but always refering to, somehow, a third dimension. Also, this question is not about programming and should be move to other community, like https://datascience.stackexchange.com/